# RESTful API architecture: Queries over multiple resources

Tags: php, api, rest

I have PHP classes for each resource in a RESTful API. Depending on the request method it will be routed to call the right function. Here's an example for a GET call on the Users:

```
Class Users{
    public function get($params){
        // get information and return result
    }
}
```

Requesting all users would be `/api/users/`. Requesting a single user `/api/users/:id`
So far no problems.

Now my question: When requesting something like this `/api/users/:id/posts` the API should return all posts made by the user with a specific id (`Posts` is another resource btw)

How would I implement this call in the PHP Class structure given above?

Handle it with the parameters in the `get()` function in the resource `Users`?
Add a new resource `UsersPosts`?
Add a function in new method in the `Users` class?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Router class that determines which controller class and method is called on a request (check out the some established frameworks like Symfony or Kohana to see how they handle routing for ideas, or even use them!). From there, whether you do `Users::getPosts($userId)` or `Posts:getByUserId($userId)` is up to you (to me, a `UsersPosts` class indicates a cross-ref of some kind and may not be the best name for a controller or model).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you think of the 'user' as a filter to the posts resource than dealing with 2 different resources at the same time.

Something to look like this:

```
/api/posts/by_user/user_id
```

In this way you could keep only one resource per api page, and apply as many filters as you want.

```
/api/posts/by_user/USER_ID/category/videos/
```

Personally I go even further and have other criterias like order_by or order_dir in the url scheme, and they can all be appended to each other, and interchanged, like:

```
/api/posts/category/videos/by_user/USER_ID/order_by/title/order_dir/asc/limit/5
```